# 500 ошибка в новом приложении django

Tags: django, nginx

нужна помощь.

В уже имеющийся django проект добавил новое приложение. На тестовом стенде всё отрабатывало штатно, но после переноса на бой поломалось...

Новые директории в nginx добавил.
При установке `DEBUG=False` выдаёт "Server Error (502)".
При установке `DEBUG=True` выдаёт "Server Error (500)" без дополнительной информации.

При попытке по взаимодействовать с приложением через `python manage.py shell` всё работает штатно.

Подскажите куда копать?

Comment: Очевидно, копать в логи

Comment: Хороший ответ, прям как RTFM)
В лога всё примерно так же 500 без объявления войны.